# Send file to Django througth Ajax

Tags: ajax, django, file, csrf

I was working with data just POSTing or GETting through AJAX until a file wanted to cause some problems :P

AJAX dosnt work if I have *processData* and *contentType* set to **true**. But if I set *processData* and *contentType* set to **false**, I got an CSRF TOKEN MISSING error.

How can I send the code with 'csrfmiddlewaretoken' and be able to manage the file too.

this is my jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function getCookie(name) {
        var cookieValue = null;
        if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
            var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
            for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
                // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
                if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
                    cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return cookieValue;
    }

var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');

function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
    // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
    return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
}

function sameOrigin(url) {
    // test that a given url is a same-origin URL
    // url could be relative or scheme relative or absolute
    var host = document.location.host; // host + port
    var protocol = document.location.protocol;
    var sr_origin = '//' + host;
    var origin = protocol + sr_origin;
    // Allow absolute or scheme relative URLs to same origin
    return (url == origin || url.slice(0, origin.length + 1) == origin + '/') ||
        (url == sr_origin || url.slice(0, sr_origin.length + 1) == sr_origin + '/') ||
        // or any other URL that isn't scheme relative or absolute i.e relative.
        !(/^(\/\/|http:|https:).*/.test(url));
}

$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
        if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && sameOrigin(settings.url)) {
            // Send the token to same-origin, relative URLs only.
            // Send the token only if the method warrants CSRF protection
            // Using the CSRFToken value acquired earlier
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
        }
    }
});

$('.guardar-cambios-pedido').click(function(){
    var url = $(this).data('url');
    // Obtiene los datos de los inputs
    if ($("#editarPedidoModal .checkAnuladoPedido").is(":checked")){
        var anulado = true;
    } else {
        var anulado = false;
    }
    var codigo = $('.inputCodigoPedido').val();
    var usuario = $('.inputUsuarioPedido').val();
    var estado = $('.selectEstadoPedido').val();
    var factura = $('.inputFacturaPedido').prop('files')[0];

    // Crea un objeto datos
    datos = {
        'codigo': codigo,
        'usuario': usuario,
        'estado': estado,
        'factura': factura,
        'anulado': anulado,
    }
    // Envia los datos e los inputs al servidor
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        data: {'datos': datos},
        processData: false,
        //contentType: false,
        //dataType: "multipart/form-data",
        success: function(contenido){
                    //things done if success
        }
});

 . . . more code . . .
```

**in my views.py**
I'm trying to receive my data in this way:

```
if req.POST:
    normal_data = req.POST.get('datos[key]', '')
    file_data = req.FILES.get('datos[factura]', '')
```

**UPDATE 1:** I've updated my code and now the CSRF problem is gone.. What I have now is that i can't access data from the view.
AJAX call returns success, but no data even trying with datos['key'] or name of input.

Am I missing the way of "sending data"?

Comment: The [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/csrf/#ajax) describe how you can set the CSRF token as a header for AJAX requests. Note that `request.POST` only works for `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data` encoded` data. If you are using a different encoding (e.g. JSON) then it's up to you to decode `request.body`.

Comment: Ok. I'll try to do that.

Comment: @Alasdair Hello again! I've solved the csrf problem just like you told me. But now as I describe in the question update, I'm not getting the data from the ajax call in the django view. Can you help a bit over here?

Comment: No, I can't help you with that. If you search for "jquery post multipart/form-data" there are lots of questions that should help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution by doing the following:

Added malsup jQuery form plugin: http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#getting-started

```
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script>
```

on my JS, I've setted the options and submited the form via ajaxSubmit()

```
$("#btn-submit").click(function(){
    options = {
        url: $('#form').prop('action'),
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(response) {
            alert('Done');
            }
        };
    $('#form').ajaxSubmit(options)
})
```

On my django views I get my data like any other POST request.

```
def some_view(request):
    if request.POST:
        other_inputs = request.POST.get('input_name', '')
        file_input = request.FILES.get('input_name', '')
        ... more code ...
```

**CSRF TOKEN on Header:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function getCookie(name) {
        var cookieValue = null;
        if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
            var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
            for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
                // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
                if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
                    cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return cookieValue;
    }

var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');

function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
    // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
    return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
}

function sameOrigin(url) {
    // test that a given url is a same-origin URL
    // url could be relative or scheme relative or absolute
    var host = document.location.host; // host + port
    var protocol = document.location.protocol;
    var sr_origin = '//' + host;
    var origin = protocol + sr_origin;
    // Allow absolute or scheme relative URLs to same origin
    return (url == origin || url.slice(0, origin.length + 1) == origin + '/') ||
        (url == sr_origin || url.slice(0, sr_origin.length + 1) == sr_origin + '/') ||
        // or any other URL that isn't scheme relative or absolute i.e relative.
        !(/^(\/\/|http:|https:).*/.test(url));
}

$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
        if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && sameOrigin(settings.url)) {
            // Send the token to same-origin, relative URLs only.
            // Send the token only if the method warrants CSRF protection
            // Using the CSRFToken value acquired earlier
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
        }
    }
});

}); // Ends document.ready
```

Cya!